# OpenGL и XML Android

Tags: android, opengl

Я хочу разместить в XML вместе `GLSurfaceView` и другие элементы.

Мой xml файл:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mglid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Button"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Мой основной класс:

```
package com.mycompany.opengl2;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Hold a reference to our GLSurfaceView */
public static GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

    // Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

    if (supportsEs2)
    {
        // Request an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible context.
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        // Set the renderer to our demo renderer, defined below.
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new LessonOneRenderer());
    }
    else
    {
        // This is where you could create an OpenGL ES 1.x compatible
        // renderer if you wanted to support both ES 1 and ES 2.
        return;
    }

    //mGLSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mglid);
    LinearLayout GLV = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mglid);
    GLV.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
}
```

...дальше OnPause и т.д.

В другом классе `LessonOneRenderer` описывается вывод трех треугольников. Все работает, но только если запускать `SetContentView(mGLSurfaceView);`
Лейаут же в таком случае недоступен.

Весь код взял отсюда.
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/framelayout.php

И сформулирую вопрос ещё раз и точно: какие мне стоит сделать движения чтобы запускать `GLSurfaceView` из XML и размещать на этой XML другие элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать такой вариант:

1) В лейауте разместить контейнер под `GLSurfaceView`, что-то наподобие такого

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/renderer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</LinearLayout>
```

2) Затем в `OnCreate()` создавать инстанс `GLSurfaceView` и добавлять эту вьюху в контейнер

```
mView = new GLSurfaceView (...);

LinearLayout renderer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.renderer);
renderer.addView(mView);
```

Вариант вполне рабочий, лейаут дополнительно содержит волне кликабельные элементы управления.

UPD. Пример рабочего кода

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (!supportES()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "OpenGl ES 2.0 is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new OpenGlRenderer());

    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mglid);
    container.addView(glSurfaceView);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button was clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
    glSurfaceView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
    glSurfaceView.onPause();
}

private boolean supportES() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    return configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;
}
```

}

и файл разметки

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:text="Open GL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Small Button"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mglid"
        android:layout_below="@id/label"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

в добавок класс рендерера

```
public class OpenGlRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private static final String TAG = OpenGlRenderer.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int LOG_PER_FRAMES = 10;

int count;


@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated");
    count = 0;
    glClearColor(.5f, 1f, .5f, 1f);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onSurfaceChanged");
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if (count % LOG_PER_FRAMES == 0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onDrawFrame: count = " + count);
    }
    glClear(GLES10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    count++;
}
```

}

Comment: Пока решительно не получается. Можете помочь исходя из моего кода? пишет что ссылаюсь на пустой объект и т.д. Обновляю код в вопросе

Comment: Я полностью переписал что вы предложили, только изменил имена на свои. И все равно получил "Приложение остановлено". Уже третий день не могу понять в чем проблема. Сотни примеров пересмотрел и перепробовал :(

Comment: что бы о чем-то говорить конкретно надо видеть лог ошибки. надо понять в каком месте падает. снимите лог и выложите

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.main);  раскоментируйте и поставьте выше сразу за super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Вот этот элемент в RelativeLayout.     <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/mglid"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

Comment: А вот это в OnCreate, за исключением определения рендера после данного кода:       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  mGLSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mglid);
  mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

Comment: <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/mglid" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_centerVertical="true"  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>  - убрать

Comment: mGLSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mglid);  тоже убрать

Comment: зря ты взялся за OpenGL не зная основ Android, я сдаюсь, сорри

Comment: Конечно не знаю) я неделю назад начал) но мне очень надо это решить) я уберу) что мне дальше делать? До этого я писал на WPF и на Delphi просто

Comment: Большое спасибо! Проблема решена, все работает! Я очень Вам благодарен!